# Mongodb: insert an object to the array, only if an element of that object in unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I have this collection. I am trying to add object(item = {label: "Chrome", value: "chrome"}) to the array only if the `value` is unique, i.e. insert the whole object, `item` in the array `foo` only if array `foo` doesn't have any other object with the same value as `item`, using one MongoDB operation

```
foo=[{label:"IE",value:"ie"},{label:"Firefox",value:"firefox"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't think $addToSet supports duplicate detection of object fields like you want. however you could do it like this:

```java
db.bars.update(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d3421a6a0100c1e083356e1"),
        "foo": {
            "$not": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "value": "firefox"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$push": {
            "foo": {
                "label": "Fake Fox",
                "value": "firefox"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

first you match the parent object by id + that it doesn't contain "firefox" as the value in the foo object array. then you specify a `$push` to add your new object to the foo array. that way, no duplicates will be created in the foo array.

not sure what your coding language is but here's the c# code that generated the above mongo query in case anybody's interested:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class bar : Entity
        {
            public item[] foo { get; set; }
        }

        public class item
        {
            public string label { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var bar = new bar
            {
                foo = new[]
                {
                    new item { label = "IE", value = "ie"},
                    new item { label = "FireFox", value = "firefox" }
                }
            };
            bar.Save();

            var chrome = new item { label = "Chrome", value = "chrome" };
            var firefox = new item { label = "Fake Fox", value = "firefox" };

            DB.Update<bar>()
              .Match(b => 
                     b.ID == bar.ID && !b.foo.Any(i => i.value == chrome.value))
              .Modify(x => x.Push(b => b.foo, chrome))
              .Execute();

            DB.Update<bar>()
              .Match(b => b.ID == bar.ID && !b.foo.Any(i => i.value == firefox.value))
              .Modify(x => x.Push(b => b.foo, firefox))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but the array `foo` is stored in the database, so we can't simply use `"$elemMatch": {
                    "value": "firefox"
                }` because we don't know the value is firefox or something else.

Comment: the coding language used is javascript(NodeJs)

Comment: if you look at the c# code, the object `{ label = "FireFox", value = "firefox" }` is already in the db. then we try to add a new object `{ label = "Fake Fox", value = "firefox" }`. but the new object was not added to the foo array because the label already existed in the db. i thought that was what you wanted to do?